# MultiThreading to Read Files

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am suppose to parse log files from different users' machines in a network. At any given day the number of machines to be read from can be any where between 10K to 40K. Also after parsing the log files I would like to store the result of each parsing (line or 2) in a common location (database table or a flat file). The log files them selves are not that big in size.

What would be the most elegant and efficient way to go for this ?
Write a console application, use a thread pool and distribute the tasks ? Or is there any more sophisticated solution/classes available in c# ?
Or
I am not familiar with writing Windows services, but is it possible to write a service a 
deploy it to multiple machines ?? 
Or 
Any other approach ?

Comment: Since the bottleneck is almost certainly going to be the hard drive, which can't process more than one request at once, multithreading the file reading is unlikely to help, and may even hurt.  Multithreading would only help if you have a lot of CPU bound processing that you do on the data in the file.

Comment: the files I would be reading are in different hard drives of different machines of different users..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the most efficient way to go for this?

That's up for debate - I dare say part of the reason for the post. Personally, I would threadpool the reading of the logs on a machine by machine basis and store the results of these operations in a SQL Server back end. However, this is the heavy-duty, production environment approach and may not be applicable depending on how much effort you want to put in.

Ideally, this would be written as a dedicated Windows Service and building/debugging these has become a lot easier in more recent versions of Visual Studio. Another viable approach is to create a console application that you can easily run and see the output of. When deploying you can use a tool all NSSM to allow the console application to run as a windows service. This is probably the least painful but slightly clunky method - other posters may have a neater solution.

Having one application or program running on a single server would be the easiest way but this assums that the server has access to the relevant shares on each machine where the log files are located.

If you wanted to deploy a service onto each machine in question and have it run locally (bypassing the whole multi-threaded methodology as you have one thread checking one set of log files on a defined schedule), then having a SQL Server back end is the easier way to go as it's easier to configure a SQL Server account and allow remote connections to it than it is to configure folder shares across a set of machines (I stand to be corrected on thsi as I'm not a domain admin). The downside to this is that if you need to update the application then updating on each machine is a pain.

It comes down to which approach suits your situation best? The single deployment requiring machine shares or the multi-deployment with a single SQL Server (or other data store) instance?